# REGEXP Oracle several not statements

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have a string with 4 names separated by commas. 3 of 4 names have strict identifiers inside and the last one has no identifier. The order of names in the string is random. How can I get the name without an identifier, using oracle REGEXP?

Example string  : `'a. Name1, b. Name2, Name3, c-f Name4'`

strict identifiers are `'a.'`, `'b.'`, `'c-f'`

`name1`, `name2` and `name4` I can get in this way:

```
select 
regexp_substr('a. Name1, b. Name2, Name3, c-f Name4','(^|, )a.[^,]+($|,)') as name1,
regexp_substr('a. Name1, b. Name2, Name3, c-f Name4','(^|, )b.[^,]+($|,)') as name2,
regexp_substr('a. Name1, b. Name2, Name3, c-f Name4','(^|, )c\-f[^,]+($|,)') as name4
from dual
```

I want to get name3 with the use of something like this:

```
'(^|, )((NOT("a."))and(NOT("b."))and(NOT("c-f")))([^,]+($|,)'
```

But I don't know how to do it with REGEXP. Is it possible in Oracle?

Comment: Without lookaheads (which I believe are not supported directly in oracle), I don't think the not/and pattern is possible directly. You need to find a more creative approach.

Comment: Right, there is no way to negate a sequence of chars without lookaheads. There are other constructs for that in some exostic regex flavors, Oracle regex is not one of them.

Comment: How is a “strict identifier” defined? True or false: you can recognize a name that does not have a strict identifier, by noticing the pattern comma-space-(nonspace, non-comma characters)-comma? Where the leading “comma-space” may instead be “start of string”, and/or trailing comma may be “end of string”? It seems that way. And if that is correct, it also tells you directly how to write the regular expression.

Comment: @mathguy I need something like this: '(^|, )((NOT("a."))and(NOT("b."))and(NOT("c-f")))([^,]+($|,)'

Comment: @Room'on - You didn't answer my question (true or false, about how you *could* recognize the name without a strict identifier). It doesn't make sense to write a solution that hard-codes just a few specific identifiers; if you hard-code `a.` and `b.` the query will not work as needed for inputs like `t. name`, will it?

Comment: @mathguy If I understand your question correctly, the answer is false. The only way I can recognize the name without a strict identifier is by checking the existence of strict identifiers. I understand that hard-code solution is not good, but in my case, it works.

Comment: That is why I asked the definition of "strict identifier". If the "name" is `t.j. smith` - does it have strict identifier(s), or not?

Comment: `t.j. smith` has no strict identifiers. Only `a.` ,`b.` and `c-f`

Answer (score 2):

This will match the 3rd back reference (any pattern surrounded by brackets).

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(
   yourStringColumn,
   'a\. (.*), b\. (.*), (.*), c-f (.*)',
   '\3'
)
```

The pattern I used has 4 back references in it, each being the name you're looking for. The rest of the pattern (outside of the back references) are the fixed parts of the pattern you described.  Just remember to escape the full stop so that it's not treated as a wild card (`'\.'`)

***EDIT:***

If they can be in any order, my best attempt is to find an item between commas (or start/end of string) that doesn't itself include a comma or space (with the space implying there is a prefix)

```
SELECT
  regexp_replace(
    'c-f Name1, Name2, b. Name3, a. Name4', 
    '(^|.+, )([^, ]+)($|, .+)',
    '\2'
  )
FROM
  dual
;
```

Comment: The order of names in the string is random, for example, 'b. Name2, Name3, c-f Name4, a. Name1 '. So it is not always the 3-rd place in the string.

Comment: @Room'on Hope that simplified suggestion helps?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but in my case Name3 can also include spaces...

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be a regular expression? Because, if it doesn't, SUBSTR + INSTR combination does the job as well.

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'a. Name1, b. Name2, Name3, c-f Name4' from dual)
  3  select
  4    trim(substr(col, instr(col, '.', 1, 1) + 1,
  5                     instr(col, ',', 1, 1) - instr(col, '.', 1, 1) - 1)) str1,
  6    trim(substr(col, instr(col, '.', 1, 2) + 1,
  7                     instr(col, ',', 1, 2) - instr(col, '.', 1, 2) - 1)) str2,
  8    trim(substr(col, instr(col, ',', 1, 2) + 1,
  9                     instr(col, ',', 1, 3) - instr(col, ',', 1, 2) - 1)) str3,
 10    trim(substr(col, instr(col, 'c-f', 1, 1) + 4)) str4
 11  from test;

STR1  STR2  STR3  STR4
----- ----- ----- -----
Name1 Name2 Name3 Name4

SQL>
```

[EDIT, according to MatBailie's comment]

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'a. Name1, b. Name2, Name3, c-f Name4' from dual)
  3  select
  4    trim(substr(col, instr(col, 'a.', 1, 1) + 2,
  5                     instr(col, ', b.', 1, 1) - instr(col, 'a.', 1, 1) - 2)) str1,
  6    trim(substr(col, instr(col, 'b.', 1, 1) + 2,
  7                     instr(col, ',', 1, 2) - instr(col, 'b.', 1, 1) - 2)) str2,
  8    trim(substr(col, instr(col, ',', 1, 2) + 1,
  9                     instr(col, ',', 1, 3) - instr(col, ',', 1, 2) - 1)) str3,
 10    trim(substr(col, instr(col, 'c-f', 1, 1) + 4)) str4
 11  from test;

STR1  STR2  STR3  STR4
----- ----- ----- -----
Name1 Name2 Name3 Name4

SQL>
```

**[EDIT #2]**

As identifiers can be placed anywhere, how about such a code?

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'a. Little foot, c-f Bruce Wayne, Catherine Zeta-Jones, b. Bill White Jr.' from dual),
  3  inter as
  4    (select trim(regexp_substr(col, '[^,]+', 1, level)) str
  5     from test
  6     connect by level <= regexp_count(col, ',') + 1
  7    ),
  8  inter2 as
  9    (select trim(replace(replace(replace(str, 'a.', ''),
 10                                              'b.', ''),
 11                                              'c-f', '')) result,
 12       rownum rn
 13     from inter
 14    )
 15  select max(decode(rn, 1, result)) n1,
 16         max(decode(rn, 2, result)) n2,
 17         max(decode(rn, 3, result)) n3,
 18         max(decode(rn, 4, result)) n4
 19  from inter2;

N1                   N2                   N3                   N4
-------------------- -------------------- -------------------- --------------------
Little foot          Bruce Wayne          Catherine Zeta-Jones Bill White Jr.

SQL>
```

Comment: Be careful that the names don't contain full stops, etc. Better, in my experience, to search for the full `', b. '` rather just `'.' ` or `',' `

Comment: The order of names in the string is random, for example, it can be 'b. Name2, Name3, c-f Name4, a. Name1'

Comment: What do those *names* actually contain? Are there dots, commas, dashes, etc. or are those only alphanumerics? I've posted yet another sample code (EDIT #2); have a look, please.

Comment: From the Op's comments, it's not a matter of splitting in to a list, or finding the 3rd item. It's a case of finding the one item that doesn't have `'a.'` or `'b.'` or `'c-f '` at the start, without knowing what position in the list that item will be at.

Comment: I understood that they want to get all values; they don't have a problem with a, b and c-f, but do with the fourth value ...

Comment: Littlefoot, your [EDIT #2] solution doesn't work if I try 'a. Little foot, Catherine Zeta-Jones,  c-f Bruce Wayne, b. Bill White Jr.'  instead of  'a. Little foot, c-f Bruce Wayne, Catherine Zeta-Jones, b. Bill White Jr.'. I need 'Catherine Zeta-Jones' to be N3, not N2.

Comment: Why? Isn't Catherine (in that case) on N2 position? I thought that you want to keep places those names have in an input string ... Shortly, I don't understand WHY it is wrong. Could you explain, please?

Comment: I need to select only Catherine, but in your case, I don't know N2 or N3 I should choose.

Answer (score 0):

I understood that I can use REGEXP_REPLACE function several times:

```
select 
regexp_replace(
regexp_replace(
regexp_replace(
'a. Name1, b. Name2, Name3, c-f Name4',
'(^|, | )a\.[^,]+($|,)'),
'(^|, | )b\.[^,]+($|,)'),
'(^|, | )c\-f[^,]+($|,)') as name3
from dual
```

Thank you, MatBailie, for the idea of using REGEXP_REPLACE!